# How to use Eval() dynamically in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    string z = Request.Cookies[i.ToString()].Value; 
    %>
        <td><%# Eval(z).ToString()%></td>
    <%
}
```

but its not taking variable "z". is any way to use like this.
Not found on search thats why posting.

thanks

Comment: why do you want to use `Eval`?

Comment: @krshekhar then how to use? i have datatable..from that i want to populate in repeater

Comment: Can any one suggest me any other alternative...my problem is that..i am using the datatable name dynamically so i cant make it constant to read in Eval() statement.

Answer (score 0):

z.ToString() maybe?

Can you confirm that the cookies actually exist?

Comment: z.ToString() not works..ya cookies exist...i tried like this also z="some string"; without cookies..

Comment: I added a new answer which should help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you investigate the ASP.Net Dynnamic Data Entities project type. Even if you only create a sample project and use what you learn from that.